# While loop & BufferedReader

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader, exit

I'm working on an assignment for class and I'm having an issue with setting up for the user to quit the program by entering Q or q.

My professor won't allow us to use Scanner because he doesn't like it for some reason and I've never used the BufferedReader before and I keep getting a little confused.  Also, he doesn't want us to prompt the user or I would just set up something at the end that says hit enter to continue or Q/q to quit.  But I'm not sure how to handle it without that, any suggestions?  As of right now if I choose to quit with q I get an error because I've parsed all the inputs into doubles.

Thanks for any help below is my code.

```
public class CST200_Lab2 {  

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String inputString = " ";

    double hullSpeed;
    double displacementEqu;
    double sailAreaEqu;
    double capSize;
    double comfortIndex;

    InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(ISR);

    NumberFormat NF = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    NF.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    NF.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    while(!(inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))) {

        //Input for the Length of the vessel
        inputString = BR.readLine();
        double lengthVesselDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);

        //Input for the water line length for the Vessel
        inputString = BR.readLine();
        double waterLineLengthDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);

        //Input for the Beam / width of the vessel
        inputString = BR.readLine();
        double widthVesselDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);

        //Input for the displacement
        inputString = BR.readLine();
        double displacementDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);

        //Input for the Sail Area
        inputString = BR.readLine();
        double sailAreaDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);

        /**EQUATIONS*/
        //Calculate the Hull Speed
        hullSpeed = 1.34 * (Math.pow(waterLineLengthDbl, .5));

        //Calculate Displacement to Waterline Length
        displacementEqu = (displacementDbl / 2240.00) / Math.pow((.01 * waterLineLengthDbl), 3);

        //Calculate Sail Area to Displacement
        sailAreaEqu = sailAreaDbl / Math.pow((displacementDbl / 64.00), .67);

        //Calculate the Capsize index.
        capSize = widthVesselDbl / Math.pow((displacementDbl / 64.00), .33);

        //Calculate the Comfort index
        comfortIndex = (displacementDbl) / (.65*(.7 * waterLineLengthDbl 
                + .3 * lengthVesselDbl) * Math.pow((widthVesselDbl), 1.33));

        //Print out the User input 
        System.out.println("LOA: " + NF.format(lengthVesselDbl));
        System.out.println("LWL: " + NF.format(waterLineLengthDbl));
        System.out.println("BEAM: " + NF.format(displacementDbl));

    };
}
}
```

****UPDATE****

Based on what a few of you have suggested I'm still having issues.  The problem with the suggestion is it's now asking for 6 user inputs rather than the 5 that are needed for the program.  Also, if you quit in the middle of the program you get the same error I was getting from before...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Q"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at CST200_Lab2.main(CST200_Lab2.java:38)
```

**********NEW UPDATE**************

This is what I am doing now and it seems to be working.  Is this a good route to take.  Is there a better way to write this so the user can enter Q at any time and end the program?  I can't seem to find a way because the input is being parsed to a double.

```
while(!(exit.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) && !(exit.equals(null))) {
```

At the end of the While loop

```
exit = BR.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear what you're trying to do, as you seem to be reading in from the console multiple times inside the while loop. However, this will allow the loop to terminate when a `q` or `Q` has been entered in by the user via the console:

```
String inputString = "";

//assign the trimmed user input line to inputString and check if it equals q ignoring case
while ((inputString = BR.readLine()) != null && (!inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))) {
       //do stuff with inputString in while loop
}
```

If you can add more details, I can add more to the answer.

**Update**

After your clarification in the comments about what you want, I changed only the loop to do what you want, and placed the variables (that you had inside the while loop) outside:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class CST200_Lab2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputString = "";

        double hullSpeed;
        double displacementEqu;
        double sailAreaEqu;
        double capSize;
        double comfortIndex;

        // declare variables outside the loop to be preserved
        // initialize at -1 because length and area can't be negative
        // and because my compiler requires initialization
        double lengthVesselDbl = -1;
        double waterLineLengthDbl = -1;
        double widthVesselDbl = -1;
        double displacementDbl = -1;
        double sailAreaDbl = -1;

        InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(ISR);

        NumberFormat NF = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        NF.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        NF.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        System.out.println("Starting program!");

        int i = 1;

        // loop and read input, and assign to proper variable
        while ((inputString = BR.readLine()) != null && (!inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))) {
            try {
                switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    lengthVesselDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    waterLineLengthDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    widthVesselDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    displacementDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    sailAreaDbl = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Input is not being used. Press Q to exit!");
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number!");
            }
        }

        // check if variables were assigned properly
        if (lengthVesselDbl >= 0 && waterLineLengthDbl >= 0 && widthVesselDbl >= 0 && displacementDbl >= 0
                && sailAreaDbl >= 0) {

            // Calculate the Hull Speed
            hullSpeed = 1.34 * (Math.pow(waterLineLengthDbl, .5));

            // Calculate Displacement to Waterline Length
            displacementEqu = (displacementDbl / 2240.00) / Math.pow((.01 * waterLineLengthDbl), 3);

            // Calculate Sail Area to Displacement
            sailAreaEqu = sailAreaDbl / Math.pow((displacementDbl / 64.00), .67);

            // Calculate the Capsize index.
            capSize = widthVesselDbl / Math.pow((displacementDbl / 64.00), .33);

            // Calculate the Comfort index
            comfortIndex = (displacementDbl)
                    / (.65 * (.7 * waterLineLengthDbl + .3 * lengthVesselDbl) * Math.pow((widthVesselDbl), 1.33));

            // Print out the User input
            System.out.println("LOA: " + NF.format(lengthVesselDbl));
            System.out.println("LWL: " + NF.format(waterLineLengthDbl));
            System.out.println("BEAM: " + NF.format(displacementDbl));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Dimensions weren't initialized!");
        }
    }
}
```

Since you said it's assumed the user knows when to enter what dimension or value, I made `switch` statement so that based on the iteration of the loop, the user inputted value gets assigned to the proper variable, since each iteration the user input is read in. After the 5th iteration, nothing happens with the user provided inputs, and the loop terminates once the user enter a Q.

Comment: It will also get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Essentially it's a "calculator" for boats.  I'm not finished yet but It reads in 5 numbers from the user, then calculates 5 separate things for a boat using the user input.  The problem with what you have is it seems to be prompting for a 6th input

Comment: @user3862586 So it's assumed that the user knows what order the numbers are supposed to go in? So i knows to put in vessel length in first, and then water line length, and so on? Then after the user puts in all 5 numbers, they type "q" to terminate the loop and get results? And this is all without any prompting? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I'm assuming that is correct for quit too.  I'm going to ask the professor in class tomorrow.  I'm not sure if he wants the user to be able to put in Q at anytime to quit or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for end of stream, and you're checking the line before the line just entered. Try this:

```
while ((inputString = BR.readLine()) != null && !inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
```

Comment: Ok.  Will this allow for a user to quit at any point?  Could you explain why it's giving an error as is?  I figured it was because I was parsing it into a double?

Comment: I tried what you have and it quits the program when you get to the end, however it's wanting 6 inputs now instead of the 5 that are needed.

Comment: @user3862586 Because you didn't remove the inner `readLine()` call.

Answer (score 0):

this is working with me:

```
while (!(line = scan.readLine()).isEmpty())
```

for this question, i guess it's like your problem:
https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=380